# set TextDecorations.Strikethrough to RichTextbox Windows Phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

In my Windows Phone application I want to set TextDecorations.Strikethrough property to RichTextbox element, but I can use only  -  `run.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline;`

But I exceedingly need to have strikethrough text. How can I have it?

Answer (score 2):

Strikethrough is not supported. If you need this you'll have to draw a line on top of the text yourself instead.

Answer (score 0):

Strikethrough is not supported, you will have to roll you own.
Here's some sample code, but it's far from a proper implementation. (It does not support wrapping etc.)

```
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock  Name="txtTask" TextAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="[Task]" Margin="0,0,2,1" Height="13.2" />
                        <Border x:Name="brdStrikeOut" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" BorderBrush="{Binding ElementName=txtTask, Path=Foreground}"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
```

Cheers
Jacques